# Python performing multiple tasks

Tags: python, multithreading, process, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have an endpoint in my API, which actually get data from different datasources, what I am trying to do is send request to all the datasources at once and as soon as I get result from once datasource return the result to user (terminate all remaining requests if possible).

What are good libraries in python that can be used?
Any Example would be great help

Thanks

Comment: Where is the question here?

Comment: @Michal just wanted to know what python library should I use in order to achieve that, I saw multiprocessing can't really figure out how do I call multiple functions and get response or just wait for the first response ... Hope that gives you idea, what I am trying to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library for this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
q = Queue()

def some_func1(arg1, arg2, q):
    #this one will take longer, so we'll kill it after the other finishes
    time.sleep(20)
    q.put('some_func1 finished!')

def some_func2(arg1, arg2, q):
    q.put('some_func2 finished!')

proc1 = Process(target=some_func1,
                           args = ('arga', 'argb', q))
proc2 = Process(target=some_func2,
                           args = ('arg1', 'arg2', q))
proc1.start()
proc2.start()

#this will be the result from the first thread that finishes.
#At this point you can wait for the other threads or kill them, or whatever you want.
result = q.get()
print result
#if you want to kill all the procs now:
proc1.terminate()
proc2.terminate()
```

**EDIT: Use the Queue in Multiprocessing for this as it's process safe.**

Comment: How would you then make sure that the first response cancels the others?

Comment: @Eli that works for what I was trying to do ... Thanks